# In IE6, how to implement a:hover?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I am using following CSS:

```
#userinfo_box a:link,a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#userinfo_box a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

The HTML is

```
<div id="userinfo_box"><a href="">Hello World</a></div>
```

In IE6, Hello World is not being underlined. How to do it in IE6?

Comment: a:hover should be working under ie6, are you sure you posted your whole code?

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) : [IE 6 CSS Hover non Anchor Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605/ie-6-css-hover-non-anchor-tag)

Comment: Is that the *only* CSS and HTML? Because I can't reproduce it. Have you tested it with just that HTML/CSS? Can you provide a minimal test case that shows the problem? I'm inclined to say it has to do with positioning, floating or having layout or not of these elements or one of its parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason why IE6 might not be working in this instance is because the href is blank. Sometimes IE6 doesn't recognize a link properly if that property is blank. Try setting it as `href="#"` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least put a # in the href.  Nothing in the href means it's not a link...so that might be your problem right there.  If that doesn't fix the problem, let me know, and I'll install Multiple IE on my VM to test IE6.

```
<div id="userinfo_box"><a href="#">Hello World</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

note that the selectors in your first ruleset should probably be corrected to:

```
#userinfo_box a:link, #userinfo_box a:visited {}
```